# Unable to run cydia extender on non jsilbroken iphone 6s plus running ios 10.3.2

Tags: ios, iphone, ios10, cydia

I tried installing cydia extender using cydia impactor on my phone. It gets installed but does not run. When I open the app, I get this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cB1o.jpg). tried reinstalling too from extender itself, still I get the same error. Help.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot run Cydia Extender from a non-jailbroken iPhone since it has no permission to use code-sign to re-sign your code.